# How to remove duplicate data within two table using left join with some condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables test1 and test2 and its structure and data as below

Table test1

```
Id  first_name  last_name   email   added_date
1   Basheer Ahmad   asd1@gmail.com  2019-02-08
2   Basheer Ahmad   asd2@gmail.com  2019-02-13
3   Basheer Uddin   asd3@gmail.com  2019-02-18
4   Mohd    Basheer asd4@gmail.com  2019-02-14
5   Mohd    Basheer asd5@gmail.com  2019-02-22
6   Basheer Ahmad   asd6@gmail.com  2019-02-20
```

Table test2

```
id  test1_id    Comment
1   2   dummy comment 1
2   2   dummy comment 2
```

After the left join of the table

```
Id  first_name  last_name   email           added_date  comment
2   Basheer     Ahmad       asd2@gmail.com  2019-02-13  dummy comment 1
2   Basheer     Ahmad       asd2@gmail.com  2019-02-13  dummy comment 2
1   Basheer     Ahmad       asd1@gmail.com  2019-02-08  NULL
3   Basheer     Uddin       asd3@gmail.com  2019-02-18  NULL
4   Mohd        Basheer     asd4@gmail.com  2019-02-14  NULL
5   Mohd        Basheer     asd5@gmail.com  2019-02-22  NULL
6   Basheer     Ahmad       asd6@gmail.com  2019-02-20  NULL
```

After left joining to remove duplicate records and I want records in which no comment and show latest added_date records without duplicate name and also check that if comment present then show records without duplicate name. So I want final result as such below.

```
Id  first_name  last_name   email           added_date  comment
5   Mohd        Basheer     asd5@gmail.com  2019-02-22  NULL
3   Basheer     Uddin       asd3@gmail.com  2019-02-18  NULL 
2   Basheer     Ahmad       asd2@gmail.com  2019-02-13  dummy comment 1
```

Please provide me mysql query of my final results.

If possible then provide me query form of laravel query build.

Comment: I suggest you opt for one question at a time.

Comment: `->distinct()` ? or group by

Comment: Hi, people here are not so fond of writing free code, so it is very helpful if you could amend your post with your current query and/or other code you need us to look at.

Comment: There are records where `first_name/last_name` are the same but `email` is different, is this on purpose ?